# How can I get Devel::Cover results to show up in Hudson?

Tags: perl, hudson

Is it possible to have the coverage statistics generated by Devel::Cover to show up in the project view in Hudson, much like the Cobertura plugin does? Even vague ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone is after 'vague ideas'... how about 'pseudo-implementations'?

Comment: I guess what I meant was: "If you have heard ANYTHING that can point me in the right direction, please write it down!" :)

Comment: I am not sure if you want to hear this, but you can always write your own plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I have been considering writing a Hudson plugin for Devel::Cover, but the question of why such a plugin doesn't already exist is unsettling.

The choice of Hudson as CI server is not final. Maybe there are alternatives that already has support for this? Time to start searching again...

Answer (score 2):

After a great deal of studying sparse documentation mixed with more than a dash of trial & error, here's a distilled version of what I came up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
{
    use TAP::Harness::JUnit;
    use English qw( -no_match_vars $EXECUTABLE_NAME );
}

my $harness = TAP::Harness::JUnit->new(
    {   xmlfile    => 'results.xml',
        exec       => [
            $EXECUTABLE_NAME,
            "-I/repo/trunk/PerlLib",
            '-MDevel::Cover=-silent,1,-coverage,all',
            '-w',
        ],  
        package => 'ARC::FB',
    }   
);      

$harness->runtests(
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Base/basic.t"             => 'Base.basic.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Base/copy_file.t"         => 'Base.copy_file.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Base/create_file.t"       => 'Base.create_file.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Base/new.t"               => 'Base.new.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Base/report.t"            => 'Base.report.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Lurker/build_data_file.t" => 'Lurker.build_data_file.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Lurker/cleanup.t"         => 'Lurker.cleanup.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Lurker/remove_file.t"     => 'Lurker.remove_file.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Lurker/write_config.t"    => 'Lurker.write_config.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Sign/add_tokens.t"        => 'Sign.add_tokens.t' ], 
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Sign/interpret.t"         => 'Sign.interpret.t' ],
    [ "/repo/trunk/ARC/FB/Sign/new.t"               => 'Sign.new.t' ],
);  

__END__
```

Save the above program in /usr/local/bin/harness.pl and then configure your Jenkins job to execute this in the shell:

```
cover -delete

/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/harness.pl

cover -report clover
```

Then add two post-build actions:

1. Publish Clover Coverage Report (w/ directory cover_db, filename
   clover.xml)
2. Publish JUnit test result report (w/ XMLs results.xml)

Save it & run it.

Key concepts:

- Jenkins does not understand TAP (i.e. output of Perl *.t) but it does
  understand JUnit XML. Thus the TAP::Harness::JUnit module adds the JUnit conversion as a TAP generating TAP::Harness wrapper.
- Devel::Cover and its options need to be given inline as part of the TAP::Harness exec parameter.
- Devel::Cover emits mega warning noise if running with taint checking.

The JUnit converted TAP data renders well in Jenkins. However, the Clover reports are lacking the source coverage view. When you drill into the final clover report link Jenkins gives a 404 page.

This is on Jenkins ver 4.478 with Clover plugin ver 4.0.6-h-1.

Answer (score 0):

Combine a custom TAP formatter like [TAP::Formatter::JUnit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TAP-Formatter-JUnit) with [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover) or [Devel::CoverReport](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-CoverReport)'s prove_cover